# What is the best way to upgrade Eclipse 3.6 to 3.7 (or a subsequent version)?

Tags: eclipse

In the past I've always downloaded the new version, and then manually reinstalled all of the plugins I use - but this is tedious in the extreme.

Is there a way to upgrade Eclipse "in-place"?  How do I do this exactly?

Comment: Lots of useful info for an older system at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/578676/what-is-the-best-way-to-upgrade-from-eclipse-3-3-to-3-4-or-future-releases - in particular, Yoxos looked interesting.

Comment: I just tried Yoxos, but I found it to be poorly designed and confusing to use.  Does it install Eclipse for you?  How do I install Google App Engine?  I can't believe that Eclipse can't have a decent upgrade path from one version to the next, its ridiculous!

Comment: An upgrade system isn't free, though, and you use it very, very rarely.  Given finite engineering resources, I'd rather have them work on other features.  Or put it another way:  Yes!  There's an upgrade feature.  Step 1: check out Eclipse source.  Step 2.  Add upgrade feature.

Comment: Sorry but "code it yourself" isn't an answer.  What I don't understand is that they have an upgrade system for plugins, so why not for Eclipse itself?

Comment: See my answer to a similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8047574/how-to-update-eclipse-instalation/8047630#8047630 (I don't think that it is possible at the moment).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The approach below worked for me, and seems to be the easiest. It's from [this eclipse FAQ](http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_upgrade_Eclipse?) and slightly modified for clarity:

For upgrading from Eclipse 3.5+ to 3.6+

- Help -> Install New Software
- Enter the release update site url eg. 'http://download.eclipse.org/releases/indigo' <- if upgrading from 3.5 or 3.6 (Helios) to 3.7 (Indigo)
- Click Add
- Click Cancel
- Help -> Check for Updates

**Note:** The original URL has changed. (I've left the original link for posterity)
following the [*NEW* FAQ instructions](http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_upgrade_Eclipse%3F#Eclipse_Galileo_.283.5.29_and_beyond)

- Also you may have to remove any incompatible updates plugins before proceeding.
  (For Example: JBoss Tools has different versions for Helios and Indigo that are incompatible)

**Update**:  I didn't try this when upgrading from 3.x to 4.x (Juno).  I just set up a whole new workspace.  I think I read somewhere that doing that is the safest approach to upgrading major versions.

Comment: +1 although I had to uninstall PHP plugins due to some kind of incompatability.

Answer (score 1):

As of 3.7 (Indigo), [you may export/import install configurations via the
File > Import/Export > Install menu](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/whatsNew/platform_whatsnew.html).

This allows you to install a new release of Eclipse, point it at your
existing workspace, and install your plugins from an older installed
copy.

Answer (score 0):

If you always download all plugins manually and then deploy it by copying to dropins folder, then while migrating to newer version, just need to copy that folder to the new eclipse.

And even not all plugins will support newer version of Eclipse so I guess there is no really easy way available to do the migration.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is, there is none. It's pointless to speculate here as to why the Eclipse community chooses not to make one. They haven't.