# How to update eclipse installation?

Tags: eclipse, installation

I am using Eclipse 3.6, and looking to update the installation to newer release, that is 3.7. Instead of downloading the whole package, can I just perform a update(distribution update)? Is there exists any way to easily achieve this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the best way to upgrade Eclipse 3.6 to 3.7 (or a subsequent version)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6883927/what-is-the-best-way-to-upgrade-eclipse-3-6-to-3-7-or-a-subsequent-version)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would not recommend that. Eclipse minor versions are more like major versions (updated once a year), so most (if not all) of the plugins are updated in the meantime. There are 2 aspects here:

- The download time for all of the updated plugins may be higher than the download time for the whole bundle.
- There is no guarantee that all of the plugins may be upgraded seamlessly. That means that your updated environment may not work well together.

One indication that helps is that each new eclipse release comes with new update sites. My rule of thumb is, that updates are possible with the same update site, but with a complete new version with a new update site, I always install the new release all together.

Comment: Agree. I've tried several times to let Eclipse update itself, but it always ends up with a nonworking installation. Doing a "check for update" _should_ be the simplest option, but in my experience downloading a complete new package and exporting all preferences ends up being the quickest way to do a major update.

Answer (score 0):

Start Eclipse; from the Help menu, choose "Check for Updates". It starts searching for updates - this may take a while, but when finished you can see a list of available updates for Eclipse (including any supported plugins that you installed). Select the update(s) you want to install and click "Next".

Comment: dont forget to add http://download.eclipse.org/releases/indigo to available sites in Help -> Install New Software